# Excel вставка с пропусками

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Есть столбик `A` с данными, и примененным фильтром. Я хочу скопировать ячейки `A5:A6`,`A15`,`A30-A35`,`A100` в столбик `B`. Как мне скопировать именно выделенные (с учетом работы фильтра названные мною ячейки находятся по порядку, друг за другом) ячейки? Когда я их копирую и вставляю в столбик `B` они занимают место `B5:B8` ячейки, т.е. встают на первую и дальше по порядку. Как мне их вставить также `B5:B6`,`B15`,`B30-B35`,`B100`?

Comment: Отобрать данные не фильтром - с помощью формул или макроса. Покажите пример данных. По какому параметру искать данные?

Comment: @vikttur а для каждой отдельной задачи у меня разный фильтр, я бы хотел узнать универсальный способ скопировать выделенные ячейки в соседний столбец учитывая пропуски

Comment: Более-менее универсально. Ячейка для указания номера столбца, вторая - для указания значения. Макрос возьмет эти данные и отберет нужные

Comment: Как вариант, можно воспользоваться надстройкой Power Query. В меню инструментов нажать на "Из таблицы или диапазона", выбрать таблицу, в редакторе Power Query применить необходимые вам фильтры, а затем нажать на "Закрыть и загрузить". При копировании порядок ячеек сохраняется.

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой код выполнит эту работу:

```
Sub DuplicateVusuble()
Dim aRange As Range, oCell As Range
    Set aRange = Application.Intersect(Range("A1").CurrentRegion, Columns(1))
    For Each oCell In aRange
        If oCell.RowHeight > 0 Then oCell.Copy Destination:=oCell.Offset(0, 1)
    Next oCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Автор так и делает: *Когда я их копирую и вставляю в столбик B они занимают место B5:B8 ячейки, т.е. встают на первую и дальше по порядку.*.. Но нужно же с разрывами.

Comment: Да, @vikttur прав, я собственно так и пробовал, но мне нужно чтобы они вставились на те же координаты с разрывами, а они вставляются в первый и по порядку (как и в вашем примере)

Comment: Ох! Я запутался во всех этих "когда-тогда"... Поправил ответ